# Reducing a dataset based on specific variables in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset consisting of IDs submitting monthly surveys that I know that I need to reduce down to a specific number.

The exclusion criterion is, if first survey submitted for variable H1 = 5, then that ID is excluded. So, an ID could not submit a survey until M6 and if M6H1 = 5, then they would be excluded.

So the specific variable I am looking for is interspersed throughout the dataframe based on month.  Eg.  M1H1, M2H1, M3H1, M4H1, .... M13H1

```
ID  M1H1    M1R3    M1R4    M1R5    M1R6    M1R7    M1R8    M1R9    M1S7    M1S53   M1S55   M1L52   M2H1    M2R3    M2R4    M2R5    M2R6    M2R7    M2R8    M2R9    M2S7    M2S53   M2S55   M2L52
1   5   6   4   7   5   3   4   5   5   2   2   3   5   4   6   6   1   5   7   90  1   7   3   3
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5   3   6   7   1   7   4   2   5   5   6   5
3   3   6   33  9   1   1   1   1   2   3   4   2   5   3   6   7   1   7   4   2   5   5   6   5
4   2   7   2   3   1   2   1   3   2   1   2   3   5   4   6   6   1   5   7   90  1   7   3   3
5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5   3   6   7   1   7   4   2   5   5   6   5
```

In this example, IDs 1, 2, and 5 would be dropped.

I have reduced the dataset down to the the variables that I will be using.  I may add one more though.

How would I delete the specific rows where an answer of 5 is given for this specific variable in the first month answered?

If any other value is given in the months before a 5 is given, then I would keep that row.

Edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of following you.

Is the following what you need?

```
data[data$M1X1 != 5 & data$M2X1 != 5 & data$M3X1 != 5,]
```

of alternatively with `dplyr`

```
data %>% filter(M1X1 != 5, M2X1 != 5, M3X1 != 5)
```

Comment: That deletes close to all of the rows so maybe I am not explaining it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't depend on the number of columns with `X1` in their names.

```
cols <- grep("X1", names(survey))
for(cc in cols){
    m <- min(which(survey[[cc]] == 5))
    if(!is.null(m)) survey <- survey[-m, ]
}

survey
#  ID V1 V2 V3 M1X1 V6 V7 V8 M2X1 V10 V11 V12 M3X1
#3  3  6 33  9    1  1  1  1    2   3   4   2    1
#4  4  7  2  3    1  2  1  3    2   1   2   3    1
```

You can write a function that makes the above code more general purpose.

```
reduceRows <- function(DF, pattern, value){
    cols <- grep(pattern, names(DF))
    for(cc in cols){
        m <- min(which(DF[[cc]] == value))
        if(!is.null(m)) DF <- DF[-m, ]
    }
    DF
}

reduceRows(survey, "X1", 5)
```

The result is exactly the same.

**DATA.**

```
survey <- read.table(text = "
ID  V1  V2  V3  M1X1    V6  V7  V8  M2X1    V10 V11 V12 M3X1
1   6   4   7   5   3   4   5   5   2   2   3   5
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5   4   5   7   5
3   6   33  9   1   1   1   1   2   3   4   2   1
4   7   2   3   1   2   1   3   2   1   2   3   1
5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: That deletes everything.  I edited my question to hopefully provide clarity.

Comment: I am thinking yours isn't working because I have X11:X19 as variables too?  Can I use ends_with()?

Comment: @SammyC Maybe you are right. The pattern `"X1"` will match those column names. But you can use `pattern = "X1\\b"` or `"X1$"`.

Comment: this reduces my set by 13.  I know there are 349 "5"s in M1X1 alone.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution:

**Data**

```
    df <- data.table::fread("

ID  M1H1    M1R3    M1R4    M1R5    M1R6    M1R7    M1R8    M1R9    M1S7    M1S53   M1S55   M1L52   M2H1    M2R3    M2R4    M2R5    M2R6    M2R7    M2R8    M2R9    M2S7    M2S53   M2S55   M2L52
1   5   6   4   7   5   3   4   5   5   2   2   3   5   4   6   6   1   5   7   90  1   7   3   3
                        2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5   3   6   7   1   7   4   2   5   5   6   5
                        3   3   6   33  9   1   1   1   1   2   3   4   2   5   3   6   7   1   7   4   2   5   5   6   5
                        4   2   7   2   3   1   2   1   3   2   1   2   3   5   4   6   6   1   5   7   90  1   7   3   3

                        ")
```

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "new_id") %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  gather(k, v, contains("H")) %>% 
  group_by(new_id) %>% 
  filter(first(v, order_by = k) != 5) %>% 
  spread(k, v)
```

**Result**:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 25
# Groups:   new_id [2]
  new_id  M1R3  M1R4  M1R5  M1R6  M1R7  M1R8  M1R9  M1S7 M1S53 M1S55 M1L52  M2R3  M2R4  M2R5  M2R6  M2R7  M2R8  M2R9  M2S7 M2S53 M2S55 M2L52  M1H1  M2H1
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 3          6    33     9     1     1     1     1     2     3     4     2     3     6     7     1     7     4     2     5     5     6     5     3     5
2 4          7     2     3     1     2     1     3     2     1     2     3     4     6     6     1     5     7    90     1     7     3     3     2     5
```

Comment: This seems to only delete 10 or so rows.  Is it because there are so many other variables with different names?  @Charlicito

Comment: @SammyC Can you repeat the exclusion criteria more clearly? I thought it was, the first X1 variable cant be the number 5.

Comment: If the first X1 variable (the first month that there is a submission) is a "5", then that ID is excluded from the dataset.  

A value of "5" after previous non-"5"s does not exclude the ID from the dataset.  

So, all M1X1 variables that = 5 are automatically excluded because that is the first possible submission month.  

Other IDs may start at later months.  eg if M5X1 = 5 and that is the first "X1" submission, then they are excluded.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is an issue of my explanation.  Not surprising!  all of the other variables use M1 for month 1, M2 for Month 2, and so on.  So M1V1, M2V2, exists also.  I am trying to grab M1X1, M2X1, etc.   Your code seemed to grab the first instance of M1,M2, and so on.  Am I correct?  @charlicito

Comment: @SammyC Try the new code :) Now it only takes the columns with contains a X in the name.

Comment: I get the following "attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped " and it won't run @charlicito

Comment: Try the new code. If it doesnt work I think you need to change your question with a more representative sample :)

Comment: OK, I updated my question with exact variables.  H1 is now the variable looking for instead of X1.  Thank you for sticking with me!  @charlicito

Comment: Still no luck.  I get "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows", possibly because there are "H"s in the unique ID entries?  I did a -ID, and that ended up removing double the number I need to be removed.  @Charlicito

Comment: Unfortunately, it is stripping away too many still.  @charlicito

After I reduce the DF to the necessary values, the M1H1, M2H1, M3H1 to M13H1 are lined up in columns 2-14.  Not sure if that helps

Comment: Maybe you can show some of the rows that don’t work?